# How to access an element inside object array?

Tags: arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

I have a JSON response as follows in the form of [object Object] under variable data :

```
{
    "name": "John Johnson",
    "street": "Oslo West 16",
    "posts": {
        "id1": "121331",
        "id2": "9089085",
        "id3": "3424234"
    }
}
```

`data` equals `[object Object]` and

`data.posts` equals `{"id1":"121331","id2":"9089085","id3":"3424234"}`

How to simply access `id3` value because it does not equal `data.posts.id3` nor equals `data.posts['id3']` ?

`JSON.stringify(data)` gives `\n` and `\` between the objects inside `posts` Only? could this be the problem?:

```
{
    "name": "John Johnson",
    "street": "Oslo West 16",
    "posts": { \n \"id1\": \"121331\", \n \"id2\": \"9089085\", \n \"id3\": \"3424234\"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say it does not equal those expressions? Which error are you finding?

Comment: This is what I'm getting when I alert them they are undefined, I'm working in angularjs environment

Comment: Also when I JSON.stringify(data) it gives me the object array with multiple back slash n  \n in between the objects... Is this normal?

Comment: I suspect `data.posts` is actually a string. What does `JSON.parse(data.posts).id3` give you?

Comment: it's perfectly working here: http://jsbin.com/tabamisoqo/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: How are you creating this JSON on the server? Just in case you are, you should never generate it "by hand" but always use native functions or libraries (e.g. in the case of PHP - `json_encode`) to generate the JSON for you. Otherwise you could end up with a problem similar to what you are seeing here.

Comment: Yup GREAT You Got it, its working. Many thanks @univerio

Comment: @univerio Please put your comment as an answer to mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect `data.posts` is actually a string. Try

```
JSON.parse(data.posts).id3
```

You should probably figure out why `data.posts` is a string though, because doing `JSON.parse(data.posts)` every time you need to get something from `data.posts` is not very efficient, not to mention the extra overhead of double JSON-encoding.